# How to slice a ByteBuffer

Tags: dart

Dart's [`ByteBuffer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer-class.html) and [`ByteData`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html) are pretty direct copies of Javascript's [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) respectively (but with *even more* confusing names!)

However there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to `ArrayBuffer.slice()`, that creates a *copy* of of part of an `ArrayBuffer`. Did I miss it? Is this deliberate or just an omission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy part of a `ByteBuffer`, although the process might be a bit convoluted:

You can use [`Uint8List.view`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.view.html) to create a `Uint8List` view (i.e., not a copy) of a `ByteBuffer`.  From there you can use its [`sublist`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/sublist.html) method to copy a portion of it to a new `Uint8List`, and then access its [`buffer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/TypedData/buffer.html) property to get back a `ByteBuffer`.

In other words:

```dart
ByteBuffer slice = Uint8List.view(byteBuffer).sublist(start, end).buffer;
```

Another way to get a `Uint8List` view from a `ByteBuffer` and then creating a copy:

```dart
ByteBuffer slice = Uint8List.fromList(byteBuffer.asUint8List(start, end)).buffer;
```

In practice, I think this usually isn't quite as bad as it might seem since typically you'd start off from a `Uint8List` anyway.